# WPF ListView arrow navigation and keystroke problem

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a readonly WPF listView and I am having two problem with it

(1) When I load the listView, I set the selecteditem in code behind. It works fine but when I use up/dowm arrow key to navigate through the list, it always jump to the first item at start.

(2) I can't use keystroke to select item

Can anyone give me some idea about how to solve them?

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information, cannot reproduce this behavior, post code please.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the problem is you need to call Focus() on the list item after selecting it. 
But for various reasons it's not as simple as all that.

See [Arrow keys don't work after programmatically setting ListView.SelectedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363777/arrow-keys-dont-work-after-programmatically-setting-listview-selecteditem/7364949#7364949)

...for full details.